# How to retrieve timeline properties of a Facebook status or photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Using facebook timeline I can set or change the date of a staus or photo. How can my app retrieve this information using Faceook APIs? I can get created_time / updated_time suing graph API, but these are not the timeline date I am setting.

Also, for example, if I created Travel life event, how can I retrieve start / end date from the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's not currently support in the API for retrieving life events / many other fields which are specific to Timeline

Comment: Is it known if there is a plan to do so in the future?

Comment: I imagine yes, but it's not on the roadmap, nor am i aware of any specific plans - subscribe to the Developer Blog if you haven't already done so, as this is where any updates would be announced